# Observing when stream is unsubscribed

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have an RxJS observable stream that I'm sharing like the following:

```
var sub = Observable.create(obs => {
    // logic here

    return () => {
        // call rest service to notify server
    };
})
.publish()
.refCount();
```

When the last subscriber unsubscribes, I need to make a REST request.  The obvious choice is to add that call into the `return` cleanup function - but you then have broken out of any observable sequence and any errors etc aren't easily handled.

I could just use a `Subject`, push a value onto it in the cleanup function, and observe it elsewhere with the REST call hanging off that.

Ideally I'd do something like concatenating to the disposed stream with my REST call (`concat` obviously wouldn't work as it's not completing).

Does anyone have any suggestions for the cleanest way of handling this?  All the options above seem a bit clunky and I feel like I've missed something.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a [`finally(...)`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md) in your stream, that does the cleanup.
The `finally` is automatically executed when the stream finalizes (error or complete).

**Note**: This will **not** work when you unsubscribe manually and not call `complete` on your stream.

Comment: My use case is only for when all subscribers manually unsubscribe - I won't be completing it and if it errors I don't need the REST call. Either way, finally isn't much different to using what I have above -. It breaks out of the stream paradigm by making the call in there, losing error handling etc.

Comment: This means that you will be constantly emitting data on the stream, while there are subscribers - correct?